# ITextRenderer - HTML to PDF conversion issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, itext, pdf-generation, spring-thymeleaf

All , I am using Thymleaf , ITextRenderer , Spring Boot to try to generate the PDF file.

Input : JSON file

Java Code: Reads the JSON file , process it to retrieve the information and save it in JavaObjects. The information will be displayed in the PDF.

```
final TemplateEngine templateEngine;
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

//reportAsBytes  will be sent to HTML file
byte[] reportAsBytes = generateReport(
            TEST_TEMPLATE,
            objectMapperWithNullValues.valueToTree(dataForReport)
        );

 public byte[] generateReport(String templateId, JsonNode data) {
        Map<String, Object> dataAsMap = convertDataToMap(data);
        String reportAsHtml = generateReportAsHtml(templateId, dataAsMap, 'en');
        return generatePdfReportAsBytes(reportAsHtml);
    }

 private Map<String, Object> convertDataToMap(JsonNode data) {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(data, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {});
    }

  private String generateReportAsHtml(String templateId, Map<String, Object> jsonData, Locale reportLocale) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("data", jsonData);
        context.setLocale(reportLocale);
        return templateEngine.process(templateId, context);
    }

  private byte[] generatePdfReportAsBytes(String reportAsHtml) {
        ITextRenderer renderer = createRenderer();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(reportAsHtml);
        renderer.layout();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Thymleaf: HTML template having place holders ${"data".javaobject} to get the data from Java to populate the PDF file.

The PDF report is generated correctly . But , when the string value for any of the javaObject with  special characters like '>', '<' , '&' stops the report generation.

Is there anyone to guide here?

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for the question.

We can do the sanitization for the text which has special characters and want to appear as such in PDF file

```
private String sanitizeHtmlString(String text) {
 return nonNull(label) ? HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(label) : null;
}
```

HtmlUtils is available in spring-web-5.3.18.jar.